# Build Failed on Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am a beginner to Xcode and I am running a simple program. But when I try to run it, it just says, "Build Failed". There are no errors in the program that would cause it to stop. Can you tell me the solution?

It just shows this:

[image]

And in the terminal, it shows this:

[image]

The metro bundler is failing, I think, but I don't know how to fix it. ANd the error message is this: Library not found for-iDoubleConversion. I don't know how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot. I think I have never seen a Build Failure without a message. Also try to clean the project (Product -> Clean Build Folder)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but I don't know how to access that, so can you show me how? Thanks again.

Comment: Here is where to find the Clean option https://ibb.co/BGPDWxQ
Also a fullscreen screenshot would be better in your case

Comment: I tried cleaning it, but it still failed. I put the screenshot on it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you know you’re using react native? You do not even mention that in your question or tags. This is not about Xcode at all. And there is no “simple program” here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to develop Apple TV Apps? If not, you have to change your simulator to the right device. Try to run Xcode with available simulator.

Check image here => [Xcode Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDgya.jpg)